# SQL Server regular expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

Wondering if it is possible to incorporate regular expressions into a SQL statement on SQL Server? I'm only finding that Oracle supports Regular Expressions.

Comment: Also see similar answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16973578/813266) I added regarding SQL Server CLR Regex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, not without extra help such as writing a CLR function or something similar.  T-SQL doesn't have builtin support for regular expressions.

Comment: Thnak you, I had noticed that it was possible writting a CLR function, however I'm on a hosted site - godaddy.com - and I believe that I can't install the VBScript.RegExp component to work on the hosted site. I'm I thinking correctly? I new to all this.

Comment: @deDogs Not sure, it depends on what GoDaddy allows.  It's possible in a hosted environment.  CLR binaries get serialized into the database so you're not actually uploading binary files to the host servers.  CLR integration, however, is not enabled by default with SQL Server.  You'll need to review what GoDaddy supports to see whether or not you'll be able to use the CLR.

Answer (score 11):

SQL Server supports [limited pattern matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489.aspx) in the [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) and [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) expressions.

There's no native regex support in SQL Server, but [you can expose the functionality in SQL Server 2005+ via CLR](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlclr/archive/2005/06/29/regex.aspx).