# How to get column which might contain special characters in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a situation where the name column comprises of many special characters. I have a solution where I do Like with all the special characters mentioned like this `'%[''",/#$!-@%^&*.\+-`]%'`
But this I think is not a good way to solve the problem. Is there a way where I can use Regular Expression within SQL query itself for checking if the name column contains special characters or not. Special characters would be everything apart from alphabets and numbers.

I know Regex can be used with C# and T-SQL. Looking for something if can be done through native SQL

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212665/sql-server-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
 WHERE yourcolumn LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx