# how to pull records with special characters in SQL (2005) Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to pull records that contain special characters like:

```
*,  +,  -, . (dot), ',  , /,  0-9
```

But did not have much sucess so far.

The column is called People_Name and the names supposed to be in this format: Lastname, Firstname. For example, Smith, Johnson. However, due to data entry error,
some names show up as:

```
 681, Smith,  *S-Sean, Tom,   +, John,   -, Tim,  ., .,  /, Celo,  0-9999,
 Maria,  ', Irving, and sometime as 'Unknown, Alexis.
```

My current query (SQL Server 2005) is

```
Select People_name
  from mytable
 where (People_name LIKE '%*%' 
    OR People_name LIKE '%-,%'
    OR People_name LIKE '%+%'
    OR People_name LIKE '%/%'
    OR People_name LIKE '%unknown%')
```

I can keep adding the LIKE list but I am sure there is a way in SQL server that can pull the records with those special characters. With more than 10 million records in the table, 
it is quite repeated to sort and look for those special characters then use the LIKE operator like above.

Can some one please look into it?

Comment: I recognize that this is not the answer you want, but this really should have been handled on the front-end. The program that allowed the data entry error is at fault, not the DB or DBA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get column which might contain special characters in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553729/how-to-get-column-which-might-contain-special-characters-in-sql-server)

Comment: @ Michael, prior to posting this question, I did a quick search and saw that post as well. I tried that too, but did not work.

Comment: The duplicate shows how to do this but in your case you should probably use something like this `where People_Name like '%[^a-zA-Z ,]%' collate Latin1_General_BIN` to include space and comma as accepted characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
select People_name
from mytable
where People_name like '%[^a-zA-Z ,]%'
```

[**SQL FIDDLE Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ee0d/3)