# TSQL - Grab valid URLs

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

I have a table looking like this:

```
Url
==============
www.google.com
http://www.yahoo.com/
www.192.168.1.1.com
192.168.1.5
www.192.168.5.149/service.ir
test.sitename.com
```

So my question seperats into two sections:

1. Getting all the URLs based on a pattern (`(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?`).
2. Formatting URLs that
   aren't valid (based on the pattern)

So I came up with a query like this for part one:

```
select Url FROM UserWebsites
    WHERE Url like '%(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?%'
```

But I have no idea How to format URLs.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Is there any chance of scrubbing this data before bringing it into SQL Server?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Unfortunately, data has been saved into the database.

Comment: In SQL Server for checking regex you need to use a CLR Function - Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5212665/4519059) ;).

Comment: Could you explain, what exactly you mean. does this query work for you? do you want to make the Query(the regex) elegant? or are you looking for a builtin function?...?

Comment: @winner_joiner No the query doesn't work, Actually it doesn't return any rows. I think it should be something like that.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi as shA.t. Mentioned Regex is not supported in TSQL, depence on the sql server you are using there are some options. if it should be universal, it will be difficult.

Comment: You can achieve the first goal by `WHERE Url like 'http%' OR Url like 'ftp%' OR Url like 'https%')`, the second is not possible with TSQL LIKE patterns. Thus, the answer is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16973578/3832970).

Comment: Note: SQL is a relational language and while CLR can addres it this kind of problem is better solved by a rich (with appropriate libraries/plugins) imperative language. I suggest you to just make a app to del with it. Also you can create a dll and register it to use as a UDF if you badly wants it. Note using CLR or UDF can be slow in  large table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T-SQL isn't a good tool for doing string parsing--you're far better off writing a CLR function and doing this work there. There are tons of things you can do with RegEx in a simple function--and it will likely be more efficient code (because writing anything resembling RegEx functionality with the T-SQL string operators is going to be long and involved).