# How to use regular expression to find special charcters

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-administration

How can I use regular expressions to find the rows which contains below special characters inside the name column?

```
 * , [ ] { } ' " \ % $ @ ( ) < > ? : ; # ! & / | = + - _ ~
```

Along with that we need to identify the rows which contains \n (line feed) and \r (carriage return) inside name column.

Example: I can find the rows which contains '  in name using below query.

> select * from table where name like '%''%';

In the same way a single query to find all the rows which contains any of the above mentioned special characters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850447/how-to-use-regular-expression-in-sql-server

Comment: You can use SQL Server's pattern matching along with LIKE --  `WHERE Name LIKE '%[*,\[\]{}''"\\%$@()<>?:;#!&/|=' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + ']%' ESCAPE '\'`

Comment: Nice one add this as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

i hope this will help you

```
declare @name nvarchar(33);
-- you can check with this name also
set @name  = ' yourname''g'
-- OR (here i am overriding value but please make sure at the time one SET statement should active)
set @name  = ' * , [ ] { }  " \ % $ @ ( ) < > ? : ; # ! & / | = + - _ ~ '
IF (@name LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%')
    PRINT 'Contains "special" characters'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Does not contain "special" characters'
```