# SQL Server 2014 extract string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server 2014, how to rewrite regular expression function to achieve below output ?

```
ABB_FET_abb_98693989-121966_20170304052411709.csv

ERP ID = 98693989  
CATALOG ID = 98693989-121966
```

In regex, I can use below pattern to get `ERP ID` and `Catalog id`, but how to do the same in SQL Server?

```
^.*?_.*?_.*?_(.*?)-(\w+)  
^.*?_.*?_.*?_(.*?)_(\w+)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212665/sql-server-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

You could try following solution:

```
DECLARE @Source VARCHAR(100) = 'ABB_FET_abb_98693989-121966_20170304052411709.csv'

SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (CONVERT(XML, N'<root><i>' + REPLACE(@Source, N'_', N'</i><i>') + N'</i></root>'))) AS x(XmlCol)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT x.XmlCol.value('(root/i)[4]', 'VARCHAR(25)')
) AS y(CATALOG_ID)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT LEFT(y.Catalog_ID, CHARINDEX('-', Catalog_ID) - 1)    
) z (ERP_ID)
```

Notes:
[1] `CONVERT(XML, ...)` will convert the source string into `XML`: `-- <root><i>ABB</i><i>FET</i><i>abb</i><i>98693989-121966</i><i>20170304052411709.csv</i></root>`

[2] Next, we can consider this `XML` as an array of `<i>` elements and like any other array we can access one item by using the index (1 based) thus: `(root/i)[4]`. The result is `'98693989-121966'` (see `CROSS APLLY (...) y`).

[3] The final step is to extract `ERP_ID` using `LEFT(..., CHARINDEX('-', ...)-1)`.

[4] First assumption is that source string doesn't include some XML reserved chars (ex. `<`). Second assumption is source string have following pattern: `String1_String2_String3_String4...etc...` and `String4` include the `-` char.

**[Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4e180db7ee0e300e42130ef671096b49)**

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case using `REVERSE()` can make more sense like this:

```
declare @t nvarchar(max) = 'ABB_FET_abb_98693989-121966_20170304052411709.csv';
             -- my points:             ^               ^
select SUBSTRING(@t, 
                                                          -- start cutting
    LEN(@t) -                                             -- from end of text by
    CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(@t),                           -- trying to find first '_' char but
              PATINDEX('%[-_]%', REVERSE(@t)) + 1) + 2,   -- after first '-' or '_' char
                                                          -- finish cutting by length of those
    CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(@t), 
              PATINDEX('%[-_]%', REVERSE(@t)) + 1) -      
    PATINDEX('%[-_]%', REVERSE(@t)) - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option:

Using virtually any Parse/Split function in concert with a CROSS APPLY will do

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'ABB_FET_abb_98693989-121966_20170304052411709.csv') 
,(2,'XXX_YYY_zzz_12345678-123456_20170304052411709.csv')

Select A.ID
      ,[ERP ID]     = left(B.RetVal,charindex('-',B.RetVal)-1)
      ,[CATALOG ID] = B.RetVal 
From  @YourTable A
Cross Apply (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K](A.SomeCol,'_') Where RetVal like '%-%') B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  ERP ID      CATALOG ID
1   98693989    98693989-121966
2   12345678    12345678-123456
```

**The Parse Function Used if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(25))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L)))
    From   cte4 A
);
--Orginal Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```